# Elasticsearch Dynamic template not working as required

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I want to have an elasticsearch schema that has some pre defined fields including an object type field. I want to have all the fields inside that object type field to be string by default.

I have the following mappings and dynamic templates while creating the index.

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "default_string": {
            "path_match": "myObj.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }],
      "properties": {
        "dummy_field_name": { "type": "text" },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        },
        "myObj": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I submit a field inside the object with a numeric value, it is not mapping that field to string.

```
curl -XPOST "http://elastic-url:8080/myindex/test" -d 
'{"dummy_field_name": "dymmy_value", "myObj":{ "filed_1": 123 , 
"field_2": "some value"}, "timestamp": 1522196333}'
```

"filed_1" is identified as a number field. But I want it to be stored as a string type.

[Field types detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N30Xj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is defined for type "doc" but you are indexing to type "test", try matching them

Comment: Isn't "doc" here the mapping type https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_example_mapping

Comment: What would I do If I want this same mapping to apply to all my types?

Comment: I think that is _doc but not sure, you can just try it with some simple examples?

Comment: got it to work by using the index level templates. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-templates.html
Also, mention__default__ if you want to apply to all types.